# Modifying values of existing text file (C Programming Language)

Tags: c

Let's say I have a file name already created named "room.txt" and it contains the following:

> 20 10 5

Once I execute the code below, I will be asked to specify which variable to decrease its value by 1.
For example: If I input "1" it will reduce the number "20" in "room.txt".
However, it doesn't reduce the value.
Instead, it deletes the contents of "room.txt" file.
How do I make it so that it **retains** the values in the file when I **enter my input** from the program?
Also, how do I **reduce the values** '20' '10' '5' **respectively** when I input '1' '2' '3' in my program?

```
#include<stdio.h>

char rooms[]={"rooms.txt"};

struct rooms {

    int stdsuite;
    int premsuite;
    int deluxesuite;

};

int stdsuite;
int premsuite;
int deluxesuite;


void availablerooms ()
{

    FILE*fp;

    fp = fopen(rooms,"r");

    fscanf(fp,"%d %d %d",&stdsuite,&premsuite,&deluxesuite);

    system("cls");
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("\t\t-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\t\t               Room Availability\n");
    printf("\t\t-----------------------------------------------\n\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
    printf("\t\t   Standard Suite     :\t%d / 20\n\n",stdsuite);
    printf("\t\t   Premium Suite      :\t%d / 10\n\n",premsuite);
    printf("\t\t   Deluxe Suite       :\t%d / 5\n\n",deluxesuite);
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
    fflush(stdin);

}

int main ()
{
    int choice;

    FILE*fp;

    availablerooms();

    printf("1. Standard Suite\n\n2. Premium Suite\n\n3. Deluxe Suite\n\n");
    printf("Please enter the selected room value (1-3): ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    fflush(stdin);

    if (choice == 1)
    {   
        fp = fopen(rooms,"w");
        stdsuite--;
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        fp = fopen(rooms,"w");
        premsuite--;
    }
    else if (choice == 3)
    {
        fp = fopen(rooms,"w");
        deluxesuite--;
    }
    else
        printf("\nThe input is invalid!");
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` invokes undefined behaviour. IOW: `fflush`ing an input stream is not allowed and can break your program.

Comment: Please check the documentation for [fopen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen) and see what option "w" does. Especially the columns saying *"create a file for writing"* and *"destroy contents"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`availablerooms` should `fclose(fp)` before returning. And `fflush(stdout)` instead of `stdin`.

Then, when trying to write the data back, you only `fopen` the file, but you don't write anything to it. There you have a major misconception of how the things work. in the 3 ifs, you decrement the relevant variables. But that are purely in-memory operations. opening the file before, doesn't change that. So, remove the three `fopen`s and put a new one after the last if statement followed by a `fprintf(fp, "%d %d %d", stdsuite, premsuite, deluxesuite);` to do the actual writing. then finish with an `fclose(fp)` again

Comment: Thank you! It helped a bunch! :)

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish what you're trying to do in *standard C* you must:

- Open the file for reading "r".
- Read its contents to your own datastructure.
- Modify the data structure.
- `freopen` the file for writing "w".<sup>†</sup>
- Write back the modified data structure.
- Close the file.

† This is necessary because there is no standard C way to truncate the file in "r+" mode.